Need help to configure autoshutdown with Vertiv power-assist via script
I have a Proxmox cluster which is protected by a Vertiv UPS. I am using Vertiv Power Assist to monitor the UPS via SNMP card. The software offers the possibility to execute a script before shutdown in case of power loss on Windows only. The Linux version does not support that yet.
So I've created a Windows 10 VM, installed Power Assist and configure it to monitor the UPS and it worked, I can see the UPS status.
Then I've created a bat script that starts a powershell script, the later connects via ssh to one of the Proxmox cluster nodes and launches a bash script in a tmux disconnected session, this script has the task to shutdown all VMs on all nodes, then shutdown the nodes themselves.
The manual test of the script worked, but when used with Power Assist, nothing happened.
I configured the script to be used (that bat script) and the threshold on which the Power Assist starts the shutdown process (95% of battery). I cut the power and waited for the threshold, but nothing happened.
I got just several notifications on my screen, about "the system will shutdown in 1 minute", then "the system will shutdown in 2 minutes" then in 3 ... but nothing happened.
The log file was no use, I can find the different events, but nothing about the script or any handful errors to work on.
The only thing in Power Assist documentation, that I did not know how to do it is, when using a script, the documentation says :

To run a script prior to shutdown, select Enable Scripted Shutdown and browse for the bat, cmd or exe file which points to the PowerShell or other script file on your local hard drive. Use "-force" parameter in the script to avoid any other logged in users or processes to block the shutdown action.

The -force I don't know how to use it. This is my bat script
@echo off
pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\USers\Admin\scripts\shutdown.ps1

Regards.
